# Notepad++ How to mark/replace the last word in each line?

Tags: notepad++

So I have big notepad file with hundreds of lines, with different last words in each line. I don't need them and want to delete them, but I'm not sure what to find in Mark or Replace. The words consist of numbers, letters, special characters. I want to remove all of that from the last word in every line.

Comment: What is a word for you? Only letters? Letters + digits? Something else? Do you want to keep punctuation if there is one? Please, edit your question and give some lines and expected result.

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: What special characters, any punctuation, space, comma, dot, chinese or arabic letters? Please, give the list. What is te delimiter between words? How could we we know what the last word is? Again, give example of lines and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this find and replace (in regex mode):

**Find:**

```
^(.*)\s+.*$
```

**Replace:**

```
$1.
```

For an explanation, this regex uses a greedy dot `.*\s+` to consume and capture the entire line up to, but not including, the final whitespace separator.  Then, it replaces that line with what was captured `$1`.  Note that I added a period to the end of the new line, under the assumption that each line is a sentence.  If not, you can remove the dot from the replacement.

## Demo